# Understanding Ngrx OnRunEffects

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have several Effect listeners that need to run until the user has logged out. As such, I'm trying to implement [OnRunEffects](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/api.md#controlling-effects).

A segment of my user.actions.ts is:

```
export const LOAD_USER = '[Users] Load User';

export class LoadUser implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_USER;
}

export type UserActions = LoadUser;
```

I'm trying to implement OnRunEffects as:

```
ngrxOnRunEffects(resolvedEffects: Observable<EffectNotification>) {
    return this.actions
                .ofType(UsersActions.LOAD_USER)
                .exhaustMap(() => resolvedEffects.takeUntil(AuthActions.LOGOUT_SUCCESS)
}
```

However, takeUntil is complaining that it needs as Observable. So I tried:

```
ngrxOnRunEffects(resolvedEffects: Observable<EffectNotification>) {
        return this.actions
                    .ofType(UsersActions.LOAD_USER)
                    .exhaustMap(() => resolvedEffects.takeUntil(
                        Observable.of(new AuthActions.LogoutSuccess())
                     )
    }
```

That in turn, causes the effect to not fire. From reading the code, it looks like it states:

1. When you see these actions
2. run the effects
3. until you see this other action.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you just use `filter`? Within your effect, `ofType<>().filter(IS THE USER CONNECTED)`

Comment: Example please?

Comment: I've made a proper answer, not sure it fits your use case but might help

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you might not want to `run until the user has logged out`, you might just want to run those effects if the user is still logged in. If yes, then instead of thinking to `takeUntil`:

```
@Effect()
someEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType<Your_Type>(Your_Action)
  .withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(state => state.users.isUserLoggedIn))
  .filter(([action, isUserLoggedIn]) => isUserLoggedIn)
  // here, you'll receive the actions only is the user is logged in
  // ... your code for the effect
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for the answer. I should be able to give this a try today.

Comment: You're welcome. As you're interested into ngrx, I'd recommend you to take a look into a template (based on angular-cli) I've been working on :) Lot of comments to explains things + readme https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter Let me know how it goes after you give a try to my proposal :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ngrxOnRunEffects(resolvedEffects: Observable<EffectNotification>) {
    return this.actions
        .ofType(UsersActions.LOAD_USER)
        .exhaustMap(() => resolvedEffects.takeUntil(this.actions.ofType(AuthActions.LOGOUT_SUCCESS)))
}
```

Documentation have been updated :
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/commit/4b606d581d18866576b9632b0537953c2b6006c4

Comment: When I add this code to my Effect classes, it seems to prevent `.startWith()` from firing correctly.

Comment: It does not fire after the LOAD_USER action ?

Comment: Correct. The Effect never starts up if I implement onRunEffects, where it did previously.